# Entity Framework Joining 3 Tables Together

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

```
var InventoryWares = SOM5Context.InventoryWares;
var InventoryDetails = SOM5Context.InventoryDetails;
var Items = SOM5Context.Items;

var goods = InventoryWares.Join(InventoryDetails,
                                p => p.PalletID,
                                x => x.PalletID,
                                (InventoryWare, InventoryDetail) => new { InventoryWare, InventoryDetail }).Join(Items.ToList(),
                                InventoryWare => InventoryWare.InventoryWare,
                                InventoryDetail => InventoryDetail.ItemNumber,
                                (WareItemNumber, ItemNumber) => new { WareItemNumber, ItemNumber })
                                .Select();
```

I'm getting an error when trying to join these three tables together, and been unable to solve the issue. The error I'm getting is:

> The type arguments for method 'Queryable.Join(IQueryable, IEnumerable, Expression>, Expression>, Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

The three vars, `InventoryWares`, `InventoryDetails`, and `Items` are the three tables I am trying to join together. The red squiggle is on my second join statement.

I thought adding the full parameter name would help explicitly state what I am looking to use, but that's not working.

Comment: why `.Join(Items.ToList()` ...? would changing to `.Join(Items, ...` fix your issue?

Comment: I got rid of the .ToList(), but still have the same error.

Comment: I wonder if I have something out of order. I want to join on the following:
IW.PalletID = InD.PalletID  and
IW.ItemNumber = Itm.ItemNumber

(IW is the InventoryWares, ID is InventoryDetails, and Itm, is Items)

Comment: So you are unable to use [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896321(v=vs.100).aspx)? One of the benefits of EF and LINQ is not having to write ugly JOIN code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var goods = InventoryWares.Join(InventoryDetails,
        p => p.PalletID,
        x => x.PalletID,
        (InventoryWare, InventoryDetail) => new {InventoryWare, InventoryDetail})
    .Join(Items,
        x => x.InventoryWare.ItemNumber,
        Item => Item.ItemNumber,
        (x, Item) => new {x.InventoryWare, x.InventoryDetail, Item});
```

Goods will be a IQueryable where each item will have 3 properties:
`{ InventoryWare, InventoryDetail, Item }`

If this is not the query you were expecting, please provide more details on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Tiago Sousa! That worked - much appreciate the help!

Comment: @Maverick - please don't forget to mark Tiago's response as the answer if it solved your problem.  This will make it easier for people trying to solve similar problems in the future to know that they should try that solution